# Perl - how to compare to the '*' Char?

Tags: perl, if-statement, char, wildcard, string-comparison

I'm writting a Perl script that reads from a config.ini file. In the file I want to be able to put under `Users` either specific names separated by a comma, or a wildcard

#### example:

```
Users=Ninja,David,Moshe
```

or

```
Users=*
```

In my code i want to check if `users == *` but I can't find the correct syntax.

```
my $UsersToConfig = &ReadIniFile($InifileName , "Users");

if ( $UsersToConfig eq '"*"' ) {
    @safes = @allSafes
}
else {
    @safes = split /,/, $ConfigOnSafes;
};
```

I have also tried : `'*'`, `'"\*"'`, `"\*"`, `'\*'` etc. but the if result is always wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: `… eq '*'` should be fine, and so should `… eq "*"`. What makes you think they're not?

Comment: You have too many levels of quotation marks.  You want either `'*'` or `"*"`, not `'"*"'`. But without seeing `ReadIniFile`, it's hard to know whether your code will work anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

```
if ( $UsersToConfig eq '*' ) {
```

---

`ReadIniFile($InifileName, "Users")` produces the string `*`.

The string literals `'*'` and `"*"` produce the string `*`.

`eq` can be used to check if two strings are equal.

Comment: thats what i though., for some reason its not working :(

Comment: Perl doesn't have such a type. And even if it did, `ReadIniFile` wouldn't be returning one. What's the output of `use Data::Dumper; { local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; warn(Dumper($UsersToConfig)); }`?